# Pivot de SQL Server en multiples filas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

He buscado en este sitio web todas las soluciones posibles,pero aún no encuentro una respuesta para mi problema.

Tengo esta tabla con los siguientes datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy intentado crear un query con pivot, para obtener este resultado.
Principalmente, estoy buscando un pivot dinamico que me ayude de tal manera que los datos se agrupen de columnas a filas.
Cualquiera duda que tengan díganmelo.

Gracias ante todo.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer está aquí:  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Tbn puedes revisarte el siguiente en enlace [Múltiples opciones para transponer filas en columnas](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas/) donde colocan 4 opciones para transponer filas en columnas y sus respectivos análisis del desempeño de cada una.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. He revisado detenidamente las 2 paginas, pero lamentablemente no es lo que busco. Trato de hacer un query que me de como salida el traslado de varias columnas a filas.  Un cordial saludo

Comment: Que yo sepa lo que planteas se puede hacer con:  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017  Suerte

Comment: Hola @JoseDEV mi consulta es hacer con todas las columnas que muestro y no sola con una o dos, además debe ser dinámico. Es algo que vengo investigando desde hace unos días, sin solución. Gracias por tu atención y un saludo

Comment: Que yo conozca hay, dos formas de resolver esto, una es usando `PIVOT`, la otra es usando consultas comunes y `ROW_NUMBER()`. En los dos casos, el problema que tienes, es que de antemano debes establecer cuantas columnas vas a definir. Podrías eventualmente agregar un etapa más de construcción dinámica de la consulta para establecer las columnas, no es una solución trivial.  Para poder responderte, por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo de los datos de entrada, y mucho mejor un [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Hola en una ocasión también quise hacer esto, por ese entonces el tiempo no me alcanzó y termine resolviendo con tablas temporales. Talvez este código te pueda ayudar a encontrar la solución que buscas.

Saludos.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[multiplesfilas](
    [fila] [int] NULL,
    [I] [int] NULL,
    [II] [int] NULL,
    [III] [int] NULL,
    [IV] [int] NULL,
    [V] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into test.dbo.multiplesfilas(fila,I,II,III,IV,V)values(1,24,5,21,9,0)
insert into test.dbo.multiplesfilas(fila,I,II,III,IV,V)values(2,10,36,24,3,0)
insert into test.dbo.multiplesfilas(fila,I,II,III,IV,V)values(3,22,8,13,36,0)
GO 

--inicio script
declare @Columns varchar(2000)
declare @Rows varchar(2000)
declare @query varchar(4000)

--columnas para el unpivot: [I],[II]...
--debes tener acceso a las tablas del sistema sys.columns y sys.tables
select @Columns= STUFF(
    (select 
        '],[' + c.name
        from sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables t 
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        WHERE t.name = 'multiplesfilas' and c.name <> 'fila'
        for XML PATH('') ),1,2,'')+']'

--filas para el pivot: [1],[2]...
select @Rows = STUFF(
    (select 
        '],[' 
        + cast(fila as varchar)
        FROM test.dbo.multiplesfilas
        for XML PATH('') ),1,2,'')+']'

--query dinamico
set @query='with uo_cte(fila,valor,campo)
as
(
select * from test.dbo.multiplesfilas
unpivot ([valor]
for [campo] in ('+@Columns+')) as pivottable1
)
select * from uo_cte
pivot (
    avg(valor) 
    for fila in ('+@Rows+')
) as pivottable2;'

execute (@Query)
GO
```

**Antes**

[image: Antes]

**Después**

[image: Después]

Comment: Muchas gracias @Luis por tu aporte a esta comunidad. Seguro que le servirá a muchos. Un cordial saludo